# How to put kibana graph feature to full use

Tags: elasticsearch, graph, kibana

Recently I started exploring kibana graphs for a use case to replicate neo4j graph database features in elastic search feature and followed the kibana graph documentation but the documentation is not clear and limited and I cannot find any tutorial for the same can anyone direct to some sort of tutorial or any article that can clear my basic concepts of kibana graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, here are a few good articles on the subject:

- [Using the Elastic Stack and Graph to Tackle Toxic Content](https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-the-elastic-stack-and-graph-to-tackle-toxic-content)
- [Using Elastic Graph + Kibana to Analyze Panama Papers](https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-elastic-graph-and-kibana-to-analyze-panama-papers)
- [Webinar: Graph capabilities in the Elastic Stack](https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/conf/2016/sf/graph-capabilities-in-the-elastic-stack)